# how to redirect SignalR Request to another Machine

Tags: wcf, websocket, signalr

I have many clients connected to a server in SignalR
but I want the server to redirect or route all of the Requests to another server , and to route the response to the clients in the same way used in WCF routing service so how can we do this on SignalR ,please ?

To be more specific

I have a server with a web app published on internet 
some of the clients Devices cannot connect to the internet 
I need to connect them to the server via an intermediate machine connected to the internet.
The client can connect to this machine and the machine connect to the internet then to the main server.

I used WCF routing services to do it for WCF

but what is the technique for SignalR ?

thanks

Comment: If you want all the request to be routed from another server then why not host the signalr in that server !

Answer (score 0):

You can make each of your SignalR machines individually addressable and then have a single machine manage which clients should connect to which SignalR servers.

Each client could make an Ajax request to the management machine which could then respond with the URL the client should establish a SignalR connection to.

If you need clients on separate machines to be able to communicate with each other using SignalR, you should look into SignalR's scaleout providers: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr

As indicated by the first diagram in the previous link, you can put your SignalR servers behind a dumb load balancer if you decide to use a scaleout backplane.

Comment: thank you for your reply the problem that the server has a web app published on the internet but the client devices are not connected to internet and i can't connect them to internet but i can connect them to a machine connected to internet . now my problem that i want to reach those client to the server via this machine i had this problem before with WCF and i solve it using wcf routing but how can be solved in SignalR

Comment: A basic HTTP proxy should work for SignalR connections using long-polling at the very least. The SSE and forever frame transports should also work if your proxy supports chunked transfer encoding. Some newer proxies even support WebSockets.